# Adding date to url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, date

I am trying to get htaccess to match the year and then rewrite to a page dynamically

e.g www.website.com/party/2013 to www.website.com/events.php?e=party

i tried

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} events
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/%year%$ ./events.php?e=$1
```

but this doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check `REQUEST_URI` against `events`, it will never match, because this is your target URL not your source. The current year is `TIME_YEAR` and not `year`, but `TIME_YEAR` is only available in a `RewriteCond`. Your target URL starts with a dot, which won't work.

Drop `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} events`. If you want to check the URL against the current year, you can do so in a `RewriteCond` directive.

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}/$2 (....)/\1
RewriteRule /(\w+)/(\d\d\d\d) /events.php?e=$1
```

The RewriteCond tests `current year/URL year` against the pattern `(digits)/same digits as backreference`. It's a bit tricky, but it works.

Comment: This `^/(\w+)/%{TIME_YEAR}$` can't work. `%{TIME_YEAR}` is included as a literal string in the regex and the idea is to get the **value** of that server variable to compare it with the year in the URL.